# Create list layer over map with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-application

I want to build an mobile app interface which basically shows two different things, a list and a map. But instead of having a plain tap-bar at the bottom with two entries, I want to show the two things with as layers (for example like the Google Maps App (on iOS), where you can drag a drawer from the bottom to the top and interact with it, but you can also interact with the underneath map when the drawer is at the bottom again).

A good picture is [that one](http://images.apple.com/ios/ios8/family-sharing/images/findmy_2x.jpg) (the map should be fullscreen underneath the list-view, and you should be able to drag the list to the top, and slide through the list, but also when the map is visible to interact with the map (pinch to zoom, etc.)).

I thought of building a `map-div` with a lower `z-index` than the `list-div`, giving the `list-div` a `top-padding` of `200px` (so that the map is always visible a little bit, and the list is not on top) and giving the `list-div` a transparent `.png` background. **But** then the area on top of the `list-div` is not clickable, so I can't interact with the underneath `map-div` (because of the padding and the transparent background of the `list-div`).

Is this possible with plain CSS?

**EDIT**: I think I got the solution, which looks like:

```
<html>
<style>
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.map {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
.list {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.layer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="map">
        <h1>Map</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="layer">
        <div class="list">
            <h1>List</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Get rid of the padding and transparent background. Position the list at the bottom with position:fixed;bottom:0px; instead of using padding to push it down. If it helps, give the list a temporary red border (border:1px solid #F00) so you can see how much area it's covering.

Comment: @Qaz thanks, i also thought of positioning it fix, but than i'm not able to scroll the list-div to the top and further (the list-div is a long result-list), or am i?

Comment: Do you want it to move to the top of the screen when you scroll, or scroll in place? You could use position:relative;top:200px; or margin-top:200px; so it moves up when you scroll, or you could stick with fixed and set height:400px;overflow-y:auto; to make it scroll in place. (Change the height to 200 less than the window height.)

Comment: I want to move it to the top of the screen (but the underneath map div should stay in place). I hope you know what i mean. So that it appears like the list-div is a layer on top of the map-layer

Comment: ah i got it now (i think). i wrap the list-div into a div with `height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: scroll;` and give the list-div a `margin-top: 200px;` as you mentioned. and the map-div has a `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` css

Comment: Ah, interesting. That means the map will have a fixed position: position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;. Then the list will have margin-top:200px and no positioning. (It's possible that margin will still block the map, so if that doesn't work, put an invisible element like an image above the list to push it down, but make the invisible element only 1px wide so it doesn't cover the map.)
[Edit] I posted before I saw your response. Glad you found a solution. :)

Comment: @Qaz thanks for your help. the margin-top does not block the map (I have to test it with a real map, but I can select the text from the map-div, so I think it does not block it) :)